# When performing a repository search on GitHub, how can I sort the results based on the repository's update date the number of stars it has acquired?

Tags: github

I used to see a button in the upper right corner for sorting, but I can't find it now. How can I sort the search results of GitHub repositories by update date or by the number of stars when searching for repositories on GitHub?